# Syncfusion PDF : Adding image to pdf works in iOS but not in android

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, syncfusion

I'm creating a PDF on the fly using Syncfusion and Xamarin Forms.  Everything is going well in iOS, but in Android, it failed to locate the image (logo).

followed syncfusion PDF getting started but even that it's not working.  The image is located in android's resource/drawable.  I did also added it in assets.

This is the working code in xamarin forms iOS

```
//Load the image 
Stream imageStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead("logo.jpg");
//Load the image from the stream 
PdfBitmap image = new PdfBitmap(imageStream);
```

Unfortunately, even this doesn't work on Android

```
//Load the image 
Stream imageStream = DependencyService.Get<ISave>().LoadFromFile(@"logo.jpg");
//Load the image from the stream 
PdfBitmap image = new PdfBitmap(imageStream);
```

Your help is appreciated as I'm stuck on this for 3 days now.

Comment: This is best asked on the syncfusion site, they tend to answer quickly if its a bug

Comment: did you put your image as "embedded resource"? just a shoot in the dark, but i had a similiar problem with an pdf file,i don't know if not being embedded in ios still works tho, because i only tried with android yet

Comment: another possibility is: did you implemented the interface ISave on android? since you didn't mentioned here i assume it's not implemented

Comment: @Ricardo Dias Morais, unfortunately, I did both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On further analysis about “Load an image from drawable folder” in Xamarin Android, we found that we could not able to load the images directly from the drawable folder. Instead of we can get if from the resources. Please find the below code snippet for more details,

Xamarin.Android:

```
var context = Android.App.Application.Context;
using (var drawable = 
Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ResourceManager.GetDrawable(context, fileName))
using (var bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)drawable).Bitmap)
{
var stream = new MemoryStream();
bitmap.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 100, stream);
bitmap.Recycle();
return stream.ToArray();
}
```

We have created the sample for the same which can be downloaded from below link,

[Sample for loading images from resource](http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/PdfSample-1438707236)

Comment: This one worked for me.  Though it worked for Android only.  Thank you.  You've saved me a ton of hours.

Answer (score 1):

I just followed `the syncfusion PDF getting started` and I think you added the picture at a wrong place. The image should be saved in **Xamarin.Forms project** and it can be accessed by using below code snippet:

```
 Stream imageStream = typeof(App).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("GettingStarted.Assets.logo.jpg");
```

> GettingStarted.Assets.logo.jpg

`GettingStarted` means name of your project.

`Assets` means the picture inside this floder.

`logo.jpg` means the name of the picture.

Make sure to put your image as "embedded resource" and "Always copy"

I add a scrrenshot here to make it clear:

[image: screenshot]